# Set a form field to the current logged user id

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a class Task with the following implementation:

```
class Task(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, unique=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    deadline = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
    edit_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=True, editable=False)
    tag = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, related_name='tags', null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    # group = models.ForeignKey(Group, blank=True, default=None)

    def __str__(self):
        return u'%s' % (self.name)

    def toggle_complete(self):
        self.completed = not self.completed

    def is_past_deadline(self):
        return timezone.now() > self.deadline
```

And I am trying to do a simple form that creates a new `Task` with a Title. But, as you can see, the `author` attribute can not be null (and don't want to, of course).

Author is implemented as follows:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __str__(self):
        return u'%s' % (self.user)
```

I tried and tried to hide the `author` field and, overriding methods like `get_form_kwargs`, `form_valid`, `get_form` to set it to the current logged user, but I always fail. Simply, the id is neither sent as post data (as seein in the debug trace), nor fetched from the view itself.

My best result has been *showing the author field*, creating the user correctly, but getting a "success_url" not found, even with the model having a `get_absolute_url` method declared.

The view I am working with is implemented like:

```
class HomeView(CreateView, MultipleObjectMixin):
    # common
    model = models.Task
    template_name = 'home.html'

    #form
    form_class = TaskForm

    # list
    object_list = model.objects.all()
    context_object_name = 'tasks'
    paginate_by = 40

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not request.user.is_authenticated():
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('taskr:index'))
        return super(HomeView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(HomeView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['initial']['author_id'] = self.request.user.id
        return kwargs

    def form_valid(self, form):
        task = form.save(commit=False)
        task.user = models.Author.objects.get(user=self.request.user)  # use your own profile here
        task.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

For the record, the MultipleObjectMixing part of the view works flawlessly.

I am desperate, is there any good resource for Django forms, one like http://ccbv.co.uk/? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a good night sleep, while cleaning up, I tried fixing the `form_valid` in the `CreateView` descendant and I got it right.

The trick is in

```
task.user = models.Author.objects.get(user=self.request.user)
```

and it failed to me because of desperate copy-pasting. The problem was that my Task model has no `user` attribute, but an `author`. So

```
task.author = models.Author.objects.get(user=self.request.user)
```

fixes it all.

Sorry for the stupid question.